# Volume of a pond

Tags: volume

> A pond with vertical sides has a depth of 3 ft and a surface area of
>   10 ft2. If the pond is full of water and evaporation causes the water
>   level to drop at the rate of 0.3 inches/day, write an expression that
>   represents the volume of water in the pond after $d$ days.

I honestly have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Can you start by telling me the volume of water initially in the pond?

Comment: What is the initial volume of the pond?

Answer (score 0):

The height after $d$ days is
$$3 \text{ ft} - \frac{0.3}{12} \text{ ft/day} \times d \text{ days}$$
So the volume is
$$V(d)= 10 \text{ ft}^2 \times\left(3 \text{ ft} - \frac{0.3}{12} \text{ ft/day} \times d \text{ days}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets model the task step by step:

> A pond with vertical sides has a depth of 3 ft and a surface area of
>   10 ft2.

So the pond can be modeled as the volume which can be generated by extruding some area $A=10\,\text{ft}^2$ vertically by the distance $D = 3\,\text{ft}$.
This initial volume is $V_0 = A \cdot D = 30\,\text{ft}^3$.

> If the pond is full of water and evaporation causes the water level
>   to drop at the rate of 0.3 inches/day

The rate means a change over time of the $D$ variable:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} D(t) = \dot{D}(t) = -0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}}
$$

> write an expression that
>   represents the volume of water in the pond after d days.

For this we need to know how the depth/height of the water level develops over time, thus $D(t)$.

We know the initial condition $D_0 = D(0\,\text{day}) = 3\,\text{ft}$ and obtain $D(t)$ by integrating both sides of the above equation:
$$
\int\limits_{0\,\text{day}}^T \dot{D}(t) \,dt 
= \int\limits_{0\,\text{day}}^T -0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}} dt 
= -0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}} \int\limits_{0\,\text{day}}^T dt \iff \\
D(T) - D_0 = -0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}}(T-0\,\text{day}) \iff \\
D(T) = D_0 - 0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}} T
$$
We multiply both sides by $A$ and get the expression for the volume:
\begin{align}
V(T) 
&= A\cdot D(T) \\
&= A\cdot D_0
- 0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}} A\cdot T \\
&= V_0
- 0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}} A\cdot T
\end{align}
we finally rename the time variable from $T$ to $d$ and get
\begin{align}
V(d) 
&= V_0 - 0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}} A\cdot d \\
&= 30\,\text{ft}^3 
- 0.3 \frac{\text{inch}}{\text{day}}
\frac{1\,\text{ft}}{12\,\text{inch}} 10\,\text{ft}^2 
\cdot d \\
&= 30\,\text{ft}^3 
- 0.25 \frac{\text{ft}^3}{\text{day}}
\cdot d \\
\end{align}